# php statement if true in the class

Tags: php

i have some class php

```
class shopYandexmarketPluginApiActions extends waActions
    {
......
.................

    if (true) {
                $internal_added = true;
                $carriers[] = array(
                    'id'          => 'courier',
                    'type'        => 'DELIVERY',
                    'serviceName' => 'Курьер',
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'dates'       => array(
                        'fromDate' => date('d-m-Y', $from_date_timestamp),
                        'toDate'   => date('d-m-Y', $to_date_timestamp),
                    ),
                );
            }

    if (false) { ...... some code .... }
```

What does it mean **if (false) or if (true)**

What does the language constructs php if (true) in a class, in my opinion is the expression does not make sense because there is nothing compares nothing

**UPDATE**
full class here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f04de7cb0efa6f680558b582cd7e21d1b622a36f

line 78 and 92

**UPDATE**
closed

i understand this code

it developers tab for those who will look at the code if (true) {always works}

if (false) {newer work} you can change the flag, and get another functionality

Comment: Exactly. It is just hard-coded into the code which if statement it enters.

Comment: if(false) never run inside.

Comment: this is the actual code written by professional programmers

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$statement = true;

if($statement) { // $statement is true
  do_something();
}

// same result here
if($statement === true) { // $ statement is identical (same type and value) to true
  do_something();
}
```

An if() statement will be run **depending** on a condition. If the condition is a constant, then there's no point in using an if() statement!

In my point of view if() is not suppose to contain a constant condition. You can but it's not why it's made for.

Comment: "why it's made for." - and I want to know about it ))

Comment: Why do you think someone would put something inside `if(false) { }` ?

Comment: I do not know, you know?

Comment: There's no effect in the code and in the result. Did you see it ever used ?

Comment: I have such structures in php did not see
thought maybe this is what new features it in an object oriented programming ))

Comment: it developers tab for those who will look at the code
if (true) {always works}

Comment: if (false) {newer work} you can change the flag, and get another functionality

Comment: Well... You might as well create a config file and add all bools that have an impact on your system. Then use the if($config_var) { }. That's better don't you think ?